# AngularJS Http Requests processed synchronously?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, xmlhttprequest

I have discovered a strange behaviour in my AngularJS (1.6.3) app, which I can't explain.

**What I do**

I do a dynamic parameter change via `$state.go('.', {path: 'newPath'})` and two sibling components react to that change in their `$doCheck` method like:

```
$doCheck() {
  if(this.path !== this.$stateParams.path) {
    this.path = this.$stateParams.path;

    this.handleNewPath(this.path);
  }
}
```

Both components do Http requests. And here comes my problem.

**Expected behaviour**

The requests initiated by the components do not affect each other. Both do handle their responses totally isolated. So, sometimes component A is getting its response first, than it handles first, sometime component B's faster.

**Actual behaviour**

Component A initiates a request, which takes about 550ms (450 content download). As long as the content is not fully downloaded, no other request is executed.

**My question**

Why does AngularJS behave like this in this case?? I did not determined something like this before. Normally, many requests can be initiated in paralellel.

**Strange behaviour**
[image]

**Normal behaviour**

[image]

**Update**

Component B includes a Highchart. When I disable that chart, so the requests are initiated, but the response is not handled, the blocking of the request is seemly gone.

Comment: This looks like an AngularJS problem and not directly connected to Highcharts. Do you have any problems with Highcharts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, that I found the problem.

The request to get the highcharts data was not the one, that took so long, that was my mistake reading the console ...

**The problem was**

The response data to highcharts causes highcharts to start rendering the new data, therefore the browser rerenders the layout, which is a synchronous process. Every request that might come "while" rendering is queued after the render process and the console (maybe faulty) displays a content download duration of 450ms, which is actual the time, the browser needed to render highcharts.

So, I am sorry for provided missleading information, but I actually was not sure from where the error come in first place.